# Sending mail from a Java app to SES by using only an instance role

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

Is there a way to leverage instance roles to be able to send mail to SES from a Java application running on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance so that one does not have to have IAM access keys on the box or in memory?

Would prefer not to have any private keys, including IAM keys (even those with locked down privileges), on our EC2 instances whether on disk or in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an IAM EC2 Instance Profile/Role with the following policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1393257734000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ses:SendEmail"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
}
```

When you launch your instance, assign to it your IAM EC2 instance profile from above, then you can use the AWS cli or various AWS SDK to send emails using the `ses:SendEmail` command.

**Edit:**

The AWS SDK for Java can use Instance Profile credentials.

```
AmazonSimpleEmailService sesClient = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider());
```

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-roles.html

Comment: It's a good answer but I am now realizing that I didn't specify that I need to send email from within a Java application running on my ec2 instance, which is why I have found that instance roles haven't worked (since I'd have needed to use the aws cli which java doesn't have direct access to). I will edit my question. Sorry.

Comment: @BestPractices The Java SDK should have access to instance roles the same way that the AWS CLI does.. if it doesn't, you can query the ephemeral access keys yourself from the instance metadata.

Comment: Thanks @TimMalone, I was not aware that one could pull the security credentials. If you want to add an answer, I can mark it as approved. (Docs you could reference - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#instance-metadata-security-credentials)

Comment: @BestPractices my answer from 2015, which includes a code example, doesn't count?

Comment: ^^ this answer does indeed specifically mention the Java SDK (after an edit, so you may not have originally seen it). If that doesn’t suit, I’ll add another answer with the metadata and another option too for if you have to use SMTP.

Comment: Sorry @MattHouser, I missed seeing your edited answer which _does_ answer my question.

Comment: @TimMalone It would be great if you could add the answer for using Instance Profile metadata for SMTP.. Postfix relay for example..