# AWS SES implement In spring boot java without using credential

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ses

I am a Backend Developer (Spring boot) and the DevOps team wants me to implement the SES and SNS service of AWS but without using credentials as they are stored the same credentials with IAM Role in aws so they want to me pass the only host in code and left credential part empty and it will send email to particular recipient.(as per their concern)

So as they said I did try with empty credentials in java but that didn't work it says Invalid authentication

I don't know how but they did implement this same thing with PHP SDKs they left the credentials part empty and it works fine with IAM role credentials

Here is my code Where I left the credential part empty

```
private boolean sendAwsMail() {
        String result = null;
        boolean flag = true;
        try {
            Properties props = System.getProperties();
            props.put("mail.transport.protocol", varMap.get("protocol"));
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", Integer.parseInt(varMap.get("port")));
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("no-reply@lottoweaver.com", "lottoweaver.com"));
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(varMap.get("destinationMailId")));
            msg.setSubject(varMap.get("subject"));
            msg.setContent(varMap.get("content"), "text/html");
            Transport transport = session.getTransport();
            transport.connect("email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", "", "");
            transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            AppLogger.writeLog("INFO", "MAIL_SEND", "send_mail", this.getClass().getName(),
                    Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(),
                    "toMailId:" + varMap.get("destinationMailId"), "subject:" + varMap.get("subject"), "", "", null,
                    null, "");
            result = varMap.get("content");
            transport.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            AppLogger.writeLog("WARNING", "Issue_In_Connection", "send_mail", this.getClass().getName(),
                    Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName(),
                    "toMailId:" + varMap.get("destinationMailId"), "subject:" + varMap.get("subject"), "", "", null, ex,
                    "");
            flag = false;
            result = ex.toString();
        } finally {
            this.flag = flag;
            dumpList.add(new MessageDataDump(varMap.get("destinationMailId"), result, varMap, "AWS-EMAIL"));
            return flag;
        }
    }
```

I replaced `msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(varMap.get("fromEmail"), varMap.get("fromName")));`
with `msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("no-reply@lottoweaver.com", "lottoweaver.com"));`

and also replaced same at credentail part that is `transport.connect(varMap.get("HOST"), varMap.get("SMTP_USERNAME"), varMap.get("SMTP_PASSWORD"));` with `transport.connect("email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", "", "");`

please point me a correct way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please refer to below link , Use instance role AWS SDK ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757288/sending-mail-from-a-java-app-to-ses-by-using-only-an-instance-role

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute your code, the AWS SDK will use a credential chain to find your credentials:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html

The SDK will work down this chain, trying to find credentials. For a developer working on a local machine you credentials are normally picked up either by a) the aws credentials file or b) setting `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` as environment variables.

Things work slightly differently when you are running your code on the server. In this case, the credentials are applied to an instance role. Basically, no credentials need to be passed, as the code is on an AWS server, AWS knows what permissions it has, as set through an IAM instance role.

In short, you need to pass credentials when you're on local, but don't worry, if your colleagues have setup the server correctly, you won't need to pass credentials when you're on the server.

EDIT: You will need to use the Java SDK to access the credential chain
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-java.html

Comment: I tried with the server too as you said but still get the same error `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException` and it works fine with PHP

Comment: Sorry, I missed the fact you had not used the AWS Java SDK. You should use this to access the credential chain. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-java.html

Comment: The SDK will use the instance profile settings from the server, assuming you don't set any of the methods further up in the credential chain. (The instance profile credentials are number 6 in the chain)

Comment: thanks for your help ...could you please help me a little bit more such as I am not able to attach the host to my java SDK code https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-java.html over here.... I mean where should I put the host